# Why can't concrete implementations of generic interfaces be used polymorphically?

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism, covariance, contravariance

I have defined an interface like this:

```
public interface IThingDoer<T> where T : SomeArbitraryType
{
    Task<T> DoTheThing();
}
```

I then define a concrete class which knows how to implement the interface for type `T`:

```
public class ThingDoerForASpecificType : IThingDoer<SpecificType>
{
    public Task<SpecificType> DoTheThing()
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

This works as expected, as it allows me to define a specific implementation of the interface for each individual type `T`  that I want to be able to handle.

Now I try to tie to together with a factory method. This is the code I *want* to be able to write:

```
public static IThingDoer<T> GetThingDoerForMyType<T>() where T : SomeArbitraryType 
{
    string typeName = typeof(T).Name;

    switch (typeName)
    {
        case nameof(SpecifcType)
            return new ThingDoerForASpecificType();
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException($"No implementation found for type {typeName}");
    }
}
```

In my mind, this should work, however it fails to compile because it complains that it cannot implictly convert the concrete class type to an instance of the interface. It will compile however if I explictly cast it. Is this a sign I'm doing something wrong, or is this an inherent quirk of the language?

I would think that the compiler is smart enough to know via polymorphism that because the concrete type implements the interface, I can return it whenever an instance of the interface is expected. Why can't I?

Comment: `IThingDoer<SpecificType>` would require that this `case nameof(ThingDoerForASpecificType)` be `case nameof(SpecificType)`, right?

Comment: Yes, that was a small typo in my question - correcting it now. :)

Comment: `ThingDoerForASpecificType` only implements `IThingDoer<SpecificType>`, and not the `IThingDoer<T>` required by the return type. You've checked the required type dynamically but need the cast to make the assertion statically by casting.

Comment: Is there some way I can constrain this for the compiler by using a covariance or contravariance operator?

Comment: Does `SpecificType` inherit from `SomeArbitraryType`?

Comment: Yes, it does inherit from it.